# C# Click event for multiple controls inside custom control

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, controls

I'm trying to make a custom User Control with multiple controls inside (for this example, a Picture box and a label) and I want them all to respond to the same event that I make on the form where I'm using it, all th objects would be:

- UserControl1
- pictureBox1
- label1

However, when i make the (click) event on the form where I wanna use (Form1) the event only applies to the background (userCoontrol1), and therefore it will not work if I click the Picturebox or label, how could I make it that the event applies to every control inside?

I have tried making a click event for userControl1 and applying the same to the others and that works, but I need to change the behavior from the parent which is why this doesn't work, and I'm not sure how I can override this.

Comment: Let me know if I'm understanding correctly.  You want any button click in the form to perform some change to the objects in that form (and those objects are a usercontrol, picturebox, and label) ?

Comment: More like, I want to asign the Click event that I create in my Form to my usercontrol (not to the form itself), and have the click action activate anywhere I click (inside the usercontrol), but it doesnt if I click lets say, the picturebox thats INSIDE the usercontrol
Edit: Imagine I have a button (that would be my user control) and it works when I click the colored part of the button (backgound) but it doesnt if i click the text inside the button

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your comment... One method might be the following

link click event of usercontrol to form1, in form1 code. lets say your function in form1 is called myButton_Click.

```
UserControl1.Click += new System.EventHandler(myButton_Click);
```

Then within UserControl1, create an on-click event (lets say "Control_Click") that simply invokes the UserControl1.Click eventhandler.

```
private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Click?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

Finally link each control's click in usercontrol to that Control_Click event within the usercontrol's constructor

```
picturebox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(Control_Click);
label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(Control_Click);
```

Comment: Thanks but yeah, I have already tried that and in fact, all the secondary controls are initialized inside the "Usercontrol1" which is why that solution while valid, wouldn't work for this particular case, I might just go for a panel with controls instead of custom control at this point but just for some extra details, here are some pics for example.
Edit: forgot link* https://imgur.com/a/wwKmr3S

Comment: I think I found a way, by making a child control public I can assign its event on the Form and that would be almost like your proposal, still not the way I'd want it but at least works. I think the main idea instead of "assign the event to everything" is more of: the click works no matter where I click so, is it possibl that the other controls just ignore the click and it gets passed to the "userControl1"?

Comment: I actually considered that, but glad I chose this route instead as it may be more in line with you're hoping for

Comment: Optionally "Invoke(this," could be "Invoke(sender," .. depending on if you need access which specific item sent it.. but I'm guessing not here

Comment: I have just found a solution, easier than I thought... writting just in case anyone else needs the same: I just had to disable every child control (since I don't need them) and by doing so, they will be ignored when clicked and the click itself will go to the layer behind the control, that was all I needed, now when adding an event on the Form it will work no matter where I click, can't believe that was it... Anyway, thank you for the help

Comment: I'll try the Invoke thing later, may not need it but it doesn't hurt to learn